# How to run Counter Strike 1.6/Source in Ubuntu?

Tags: counter-strike

I tried to run it with wine, but it didn't work.
The cursor shows loading for a few seconds but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Counter-Strike and Counter-Strike: Source are available for Linux through Steam.